# What exactly does trunc(date, 'IW')?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-formatting

For my project I need to have an absolute numerical correspondence between days of the week and 1...7 values.

As you probably know the association between days and numbers can vary according to the locale, for example in Germany Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7, while in US Monday is 2 while Sunday is 1.

So, searching for a solution, I found the following code which seems working regardless of the locale, assigning Monday=1...Sunday=7:

```
1 + TRUNC (date) - TRUNC (date, 'IW')
```

Can someone explain me how does it work? In particular I just can't understand what this instruction:

```
TRUNC (date, 'IW')
```

exactly does.

Comment: trunc(date,'IW') returns the first day of the week and is not affected by the nls_territory settings, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084. Only the format string DAY, DY, and D are affected.

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss um, no. IW returns the first day of the ISO week (Monday) and is therefore totally unaffected by the nls_territory_settings.

Comment: @Boneist You are right, my first answer was to fast :-D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`TRUNC(DATE,'IW')` returns the first day of the week. For me `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW)` returns Monday.  Today is Tuesday Feb 21. Subtract from that `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')` which would be Monday the 20th, and you'll get `1` (because `21-20=1`).  Add `1` onto that as you do in the beginning of your equation and you get `2`, which we associate with Tuesday.

Comment: I love the explanation with example, instead of just putting official doc. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The very basic concept of **ISO** week is to make it **NLS territory independent**.

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm),

> Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.

A week starts on a **Monday** and ends on a **Sunday**.

Comment: And just for curiosity, [the link to the Overview of Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch1overview.htm#NLSPG001)