# code in sql does not meet the AND condition

Tags: sql, oracle

What I want is that if the day in `date_prestamo` is 6 and the day in `return date` is 6 then do not show that record. But the filter in the commented condition  is not doing it.

```
--no funciona LA CONDICION COMENTADA
SELECT e.ID_LECTOR,e.NOMBRE, p.FECHA_PRESTAMO, p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION
FROM ESTUDIANTE e
JOIN PRESTAMO p
ON e.ID_LECTOR = p.ID_LECTOR
GROUP BY e.ID_LECTOR,e.NOMBRE, p.FECHA_PRESTAMO, p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION
--HAVING ((EXTRACT(DAY FROM  p.FECHA_PRESTAMO) <> 06)
--AND (EXTRACT(DAY FROM  p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION) <> 06))
ORDER BY ID_LECTOR;
```

Without  `HAVING ((EXTRACT`...... it selects:

```
19044429-9  Erato   16/06/17    21/06/17
19044429-9  Erato   18/09/17    24/09/17
19044429-9  Erato   11/04/17    15/04/17
19044429-9  Erato   03/10/17    06/10/17
```

With HAVING ((EXTRACT..... it selects:

```
19044429-9  Erato   18/09/17    24/09/17
19044429-9  Erato   11/04/17    15/04/17
19044429-9  Erato   16/06/17    21/06/17
```

Comment: but what is your expected result?

Comment: I hope it prints the same result that is generated without the HAVING condition, since this time the record that erases is the one that has dates "03/10/17 , 06/10/17", and what I want is to erase the records in which both days are 06, and not just one.

Comment: I think those filters should be in your where clause, not your having clause.

Comment: I put the same condition with where above the group by but it does not work either ...

Comment: To troubleshoot, filter using the where clause, and include the two extract functions in your select clause.

Comment: 3/10 is Friday, 6/10 is Sat so probably some kind of timing issue.

Comment: and what would I have to do then?

Answer (score 1):

I think its your NLS settings

Use this to get day #, without changing settings:

```
1 + TRUNC (date) - TRUNC (date, 'IW'). --<>6 in your case
```

[Similar SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603365/what-exactly-does-truncdate-iw)

[Oracle community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2207756)

Copy and paste this query to see if it resolves your issue:

```
SELECT e.ID_LECTOR,e.NOMBRE, p.FECHA_PRESTAMO, p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION
FROM ESTUDIANTE e
JOIN PRESTAMO p
ON e.ID_LECTOR = p.ID_LECTOR
GROUP BY e.ID_LECTOR,e.NOMBRE, p.FECHA_PRESTAMO, p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION
HAVING ( 1 + TRUNC (p.FECHA_PRESTAMO) - TRUNC (p.FECHA_PRESTAMO, 'IW') ) <> 06)
AND  ( 1 + TRUNC (p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION) - TRUNC (p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION, 'IW') ) <> 06)
ORDER BY ID_LECTOR;
```

Comment: I don't understand, where do I have to put that code?

Comment: @ricardobarros this process requires some effort on your side.  Research the issue.  Check my links.  You will get there!!

Comment: @eoins - if you're not willing to help the OP get to a resolution what is the point? You have posted half an answer. Although as your half-answer points in the wrong direction it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @apc we have different understandings of the issue.  I think a lot of that has to do with the format of the question.  I also respect your right to comment, down vote on an answer you don't see as helpful.  In this case I think there wasn't a ton of effort in the question so I wanted to post an answer where op had to work a bit to get the solution, not just copy/paste.  Alas I gave up and provided what I think may be the solution.  Interested to see if it works out!

Comment: @ricardobarros try the query at the bottom of my recently edited answer

Comment: @eoins - thank you for your respect, I appreciate it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> "I want is that if the day in "date_prestamo" is 6 and the day in "return date" is 6 then do not show that record"

It's a problem in Boolean logic. The effect of a condition  `NOT x AND NOT y` is to exclude records where either `x` or `y` is true. You need to use an `OR` in your condition.

You should use a WHERE clause to filter rather than HAVING.

```
select e.id_lector,e.nombre, p.fecha_prestamo, p.fecha_devolucion
from estudiante e
join prestamo p
on e.id_lector = p.id_lector
where ((extract(day from  p.fecha_prestamo) <> 06)
or (extract(day from  p.fecha_devolucion) <> 06))
order by e.id_lector, p.fecha_prestamo;
```

This works, and I have written an Oracle LiveSQL demo to prove it. [Check it out](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/fij9o1d8gx4m32xc5ioi6igt5).

Comment: APC in the comments op says 'I want is to erase the records in which both days are 06, and not just one'.  Also effect of not x and not y only excludes where Both are true...not either.  It's a NAND

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved by having your condition in WHERE clause

```
SELECT e.ID_LECTOR,
       e.NOMBRE, 
       p.FECHA_PRESTAMO, 
       p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION
  FROM ESTUDIANTE e
  JOIN PRESTAMO p
    ON e.ID_LECTOR = p.ID_LECTOR
 WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM  p.FECHA_PRESTAMO) <> 06
   AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM  p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION) <> 06)
 ORDER BY e.ID_LECTOR;
```

Comment: show us your table structures for ESTUDIANTE and PRESTAMO and sample data from those tables